# Are there any good Java thread migration packages?

Tags: java, migration, multithreading

There has been a tremendous amount of research on migrating Java threads between different JVMs on different machines, but is there some publicly available, maintained, de facto implementation that everyone uses?  If there is not one good implementation, but multiple ones, which one do you guys recommend and why?

(Note: I'm not talking about database migrations, I'm not asking about Hadoop, RMI, actors, or looking for any other way of doing distributed computing, I need information specifically on thread migration for Java, not Scala [yes I'm aware of the continuations in bleeding edge] or anything else which can sit on the JVM.)

Comment: Sounds interesting - looking forward to answers too :)

Comment: I remember a project being done some years ago, don't know about the current status but it seems to be maintained: http://mars.ing.unimo.it/wiki/index.php/Mobile_JikesRVM

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that but it would be best if I could use the regular JVM.  Still looks interesting though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you are after but...

I know of a couple projects using [javaflow](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/javaflow/) to migrate between JVMs. The project needs a few more users to finally see a release though. And contributors that are up to the task are hard to come by. But maybe give it a try. It has a few restrictions/overhead compared to jvm-native migrations.

You might also might want to have a look into this [paper about mobile agent migrations](http://vafer.org/blog/20061206232546).

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting.  Didn't know there was an Apache project for continuations.  This looks to offer similar functionality to the delimited continuations plugin for Scala?